# Compiling with different versions of gcc on ubuntu yields different results

Tags: c++, c, ubuntu, gcc, g++

So I have a project setup somthing like this:

- `myfile.cpp` which includes:

  - `fsl_clock.h`

Where myfile is a c++ file and fsl_clock.h is a pure C header file from NXP where a version of it can be seen [here](https://gitlab.exmachina.fr/fw-libs/mbed-os/blob/a007d912ac70df4a8e3fb569cd66ee52c28e2f43/hal/targets/hal/TARGET_Freescale/TARGET_KSDK2_MCUS/TARGET_KL43Z/drivers/fsl_clock.h)

My file looks like:

```
#include "fsl_clock.h"
```

Now I do have more stuff in my file, but I emptied it until I was left with just that.

Here are the compilations I have tried along with results:

- With the arm cross-compiler `arm-none-eabi-g++` this compiles fine.
- With host (x86Linux) g++ --version `7.3.0-16ubuntu3` it works fine
- With host (x86Linux) g++ --version `7.3.0-27ubuntu1~18.04` it gives loads of strange errors.

The errors that I get are things like:

`device/MIMX8MQ6_cm4.h8856:51: error 'reinterpret_cast<CMM_Type*>(808976384)' is not a constant expression`

Where the line of code is pure C and looks like:

```
kCLOCK_RootM4 = (uint32_t)(&(CCM)->ROOT[1].TARGET_ROOT)
```

Where CCM is defined as:

```
#define CCM_BASE (0x30380000u)
#define CCM ((CCM_Type*)CCM_BASE)
```

So it looks like the newer g++ `7.3.0-27ubuntu1~18.04` (perhaps correctly) is doing c++ things (e.g. `reinterpret_cast`) in the C-style included header code. The older compiler `7.3.0-16ubuntu3` is not behaving the same way - and the compile goes ok.

Can anyone say what the difference between the two compilers is and why one works and the other does not? Both compilers gnu g++ have the same g++ version 7.3.0. But I don't really understand the suffix `16ubuntu3` vs `27ubuntu1~18.04` and why that might change the behaviour...

**Note** Now, I know that for my host build I don't really want to be including board specific code on my host build, but that is a different matter. I am more interested at the moment in understanding why there is a difference between the two compilers.

**Update**

For the host build the compiler line looks like:

```
g++ -w -Isource/drivers -Isource/board -Isource/device -m32 -g -std=c++11 -c source/myfile.cpp -o out.o
```

The CMM_Type (having to hand copy it as the original is buried in the NXP website) looks like (note its abbrieviated because there is too much to copy - but its structs of uint32_t's):

```
typedef struct {
   volatile uint32_t GPR0;
   volatile uint32_t GPR0_SET;
   struct {
      :
   } PLL_CTRL[39];
      :
   struct {
      volatile uint32_t TARGET_ROOT;
      volatile uint32_t TARGET_ROOT_SET;
      volatile uint32_t TARGET_ROOT_CLR;
         :
   } ROOT[142];
} CCM_Type;
```

**Minimal Example - Online GDB**
I have made a minimal example - it does not compile with online GDB but it does produce the errors I explained on my compiler. Link is [here](https://onlinegdb.com/BkVisx7B4)

**Minimal - Wandbox**
Exactly the same code as online GDB example, but this actually displays the same error I got: [here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/XrzIF8IPBAsCS6Ln)

**The minimal Example Code**

```
#include <stdint.h>

typedef struct {
    struct {
        volatile uint32_t TARGET_ROOT;
    } ROOT[4];
} CCM_Type;

#define CCM_BASE (0x30380000u)
#define CCM ((CCM_Type *)CCM_BASE)

typedef enum _clock_root_control
{
    kCLOCK_RootM4 = (uint32_t)(&(CCM)->ROOT[1].TARGET_ROOT)
} clock_root_control_t;

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Could it be because you're compiling C code as C++?

Comment: All sorts of possible explanations, including potential that converting an `unsigned` to a pointer and dereferencing that pointer yields undefined behaviour.   Without more information (e.g. what is `CCM_Type`, given that the usage implies it is a data structure?) anyone trying to help will have to resort to guesswork.   Read up on providing a [mcve] - a small sample of code that demonstrates the problem, and that other people can use to get the same symptoms.  That will take effort, but significantly improve your chances of getting useful advice.

Comment: @rustyx yes, that probably is the reason for the errors - but I am specifically interested in why the error occurs only on the newer compiler (27ubuntu~18.04) and not the older one.

Comment: @Peter An issue I have with this is that my code it litterally 1 line. The NXP code can be found in the link - this is not code I am editing. But I am not really trying to debug the error - I am trying to figure out what could be the difference with the compilers - i.e. why do two flavours of the compilers both gcc version 7.3.0 do different things. I will find the CCM_Type struct and post it up to give the complete picture of that specific line

Comment: The suffix denotes a packaged version based on upstream version `7.3.0`. This may include specific changes needed for packaging or for the target system, bug fixes that are not yet released or backported from a newer upstream version... Obviously the newer version includes lots of changes, see https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gcc-7/7.3.0-27ubuntu1~18.04  (I don't know which change might be related to the different behaviour in your case.) This text may be related to your problem: https://arne-mertz.de/2017/06/stepping-away-from-define/

Comment: It's not clear why the compiler would think that expression needs to be a constant expression. More context is needed.

Comment: So I have added the comiler line I used and the CCM_Type (or part of it).  So I can probably cobble these things together into  an example - I will try this.

Comment: The thing I think is interesting is not that it decided to think of your C-style cast as a C++ `reinterpret_cast` somewhere deep in the bowels of the compiler, but that it thinks that it's required to be `constexpr`. Something more about the context of the `kCLOCK_RootM4 = (uint32_t)(&(CCM)->ROOT[1].TARGET_ROOT)` would be nice.

Comment: Have you tried to wrap your include in `#extern "C" {` ...`}`?

Comment: Ok I have added the exact code the causes the issue in a minimal compiler exampe (see link at the end of my question)

Comment: @Omnifarious so I added a link to the example code

Comment: @KaiPetzke I did try this... no change though  : (

Comment: Sorry for the lots of comments - but I have updated a new link to wanbox with the same example. This one behaives like my compiler so you can see the errors...

Comment: Please post a [mcve] here, not as links. The links are helpful but insufficient. If you are compiling with g++ then it is C++ not C, not to mention there isn't `reinterpret_cast`s in C.

Comment: @PasserBy but that is kind of my question - why would one compiler work (given the same compile parameters) and the other not - regardless of the code being "wrong". Ok I will cut/paste the example over. I thought it was useful to have the output visible...

Comment: I don't think we should not even consider, let alone attempt to debug, the compilation of C with a C++ compiler when the code was not marked as `extern "C"`. Note that the file `fsl_clock.h` does not contain this conditional on the the `__cplusplus` macro, unlike many C other header files.

Comment: There is no "pure C". C is an impure (that is, side-effectful) language. You are compiling a C++ program anyway. The fact that some header or another was written with a C compiler in mind doesn't make your program any more C and less C++. So C is utterly irrelevant for this problem.

Comment: Code in the minimal example is not valid C and not valid C++. Enumerators need to be constant expressions in either language. `(uint32_t)(&(CCM)->ROOT[1].TARGET_ROOT)` isn't one. There's nothing wrong with your compiler. The original package is broken and needs to be fixed. It relied on a non-portable and probably undocumented compiler extension that nobody promised to be there forever, and lo and behold, it isn't there any more.

Comment: @n.m. ah ok - so we are saying that the crosscompiler and the older gcc supported some non-standard extension, and possibly it has now been remove/changed in the newer version? - that would probably explain the issue. I'll have to talk to NXP to see if that have a fix for that. Thanks

Comment: @code_fodder yes this is what seems to be the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
typedef enum _clock_root_control
{
    kCLOCK_RootM4 = (uint32_t)(&(CCM)->ROOT[1].TARGET_ROOT)
} clock_root_control_t;
```

This code isn't valid in either C or C++.

In C++, an enumerator must be a constant expression. A constant expression cannot involve `reinterpret_cast`. A C-style cast from pointer to integer is equivalent to `reinterpret_cast`.

In C, an enumerator must be an integer constant expression. An integer constant expression cannot involve pointer operands.

A way to fix this is to replace the expression with an equivalent constant expression, e.g.

```
CCM_BASE + offsetof(CCM_Type, ROOT[1].TARGET_ROOT)
```

[Live example](https://wandbox.org/permlink/dPqZxo5CR11H3Nvw)

Answer (score 2):

`reinterpret_cast` and C style casts cannot be evaluated by the compiler at compile time, and this is particularly true when they create pointers that you then dereference. `enum` constants need to acquire values at compile time. What I would do in this situation is use the integer value `CCM_BASE` and `offsetof`.

```
#include <cstddef>

typedef enum _clock_root_control
{
    kCLOCK_RootM4 = CCM_BASE + offsetof(CCM_Type, ROOT[1].TARGET_ROOT)
} clock_root_control_t;
```

You know that all of your pointer dereferencing in your original example is pointless because you're just using the `&` operator to get an address. But, it doesn't matter. That dereferencing must still be valid and executable for the compiler to evaluate it at compile time. The address you're working with is meaningless to your compiler. Who knows what's there, or even if it refers to a mapped page? And certainly compiling a C++ program shouldn't result in random mucking about in the compiler's memory anyway.

And this is true for either C or C++. Since your code is technically undefined behavior, it may randomly work for some compilers. And most compilers that target platforms on which you'd want to actually use that sort of code will do what you expect when the code is executed at run time.

But, for compile time evaluation, the `offsetof` macro in `<csstddef>` handles all those kinds of details for you and is defined behavior. It's what you want and need here.